# How can I diagose 100% CPU consume of svnserve.exe?

Tags: performance, svn, monitoring

Our Subversion server goes to 100% CPU consume after some hours of work. A restart solve the problem for some hours only. The commit and checkout will be very slow in this case.

How can I find the cause of the problem and solve it. Is there a monitor that show the running command and which client has produce it?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by investigating the `svnserve` with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see if there is also a lot of disk I/O or if the load is in user space or interrupts or DPCs, then I would use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out what is really doing. Pay attention that Process Monitor will increase significantly the load on the server.

Comment: This can helpful if I a developer of svnserve. But I am a user. This information will only show where the CPU is consumed but not why.

Comment: I agree. The result depend on the skill of the one who use those tools. You can use WireShark to record the network traffic. Correlate this with CPU usage and you will find the culprit.